# Travel in Quantum Realm in Ant-Man and the Wasp

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

From the movie *Ant-Man*  we know that Janet Van Dyke got inside the missile which was lost in the sea.

> The duo undertook many S.H.I.E.L.D. operations, until a mission in
>   1987 to disarm a Soviet ICBM en-route to the United States. In order
>   to stop the missile, Janet disabled her regulator to shrink small
>   enough to enter the missile and though the mission was successful,
>   Janet was lost to the Quantum Realm.

Later, in the film *Ant-Man and the Wasp* ,through entanglement with Scott, She manages to send her coordinates and Hank Pym goes in there and gets her.

My question is, how did Hank travel thousands of miles and go to the Pacific Ocean to get her? Considering his size of atomic levels, I believe it must be difficult. Is there a scientific explanation which allows people/things to travel large distances in quantum theory?

Comment: I mean, they are in San Francisco

Comment: There is nothing remotely scientific about the Quantum Realm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Space and time are bonkers in the quantum realm.

It's possible that while floating around she got (maybe even exponentially) closer to home.

> **SF**: So there are layers that time does not pass by?
>
> **KF**: That’s what they’ve told us.  They’ve told us that it, time and physics and space work very differently down there.  But that was part of a, that was a big question during the development process.  And as usual, you’re the first one to pick on it a little bit, which is… should she have aged or not?  And we felt that new Quantum Realm, we could justify either one.  But that ultimately you wanna have an emotional reunion with Michael Douglas, an emotional reunion with Evangeline Lily and our first instinct had always been specifically now Michelle Pfeiffer from that first movie.  It felt like it should be somebody who’s the right age.  As opposed to Michael Douglas with somebody who has not aged.  Or Evangeline Lily connecting with somebody who’s not aged.  That just adds another layer of sort of sci-fi weirdness.  Yeah.  And we’re not afraid of sci-fi weirdness.  I love it.  But not in that case.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Kevin Feige Explains How They Planned ‘Ant-Man and The Wasp’ Alongside ‘Infinity War,’ the Disney Streaming Service and More [Interview] - Slashfilm](https://www.slashfilm.com/kevin-feige-interview-ant-man-and-the-wasp/)</sub>

Also, different parts of the Quantum Realm have different "perceptions" of time and space, so this might have contributed to shortening the distance Hank needed to travel.